# How to install gdal in virtuallenv?

Tags: installation, virtualenv, gdal, linux-mint

Good morning, I have installed gdal in my computer hoping that it would work on my virtuallenv environment, but it is not working even though after the command sudo apt install gdal-bin python3-gdal I receive this message:

> Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
>   Construindo árvore de dependências
>    Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
>    gdal-bin is already the newest version (2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0).
>    python3-gdal is already the newest version (2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0).
>    0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 0 não atualizados.

According to this message, gdal should be installed, right? What am I doing wrong? How do I install it? By the way, I am using linux mint 19.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install python3-gdal you are actually installing it in your operating system's python, that means virtual enviroments can't see the library.

You need to `pip install gdal` inside your enviroment so you can use it.

If you have problems installing it you can try making a conda enviroment instead, and install all of your requirements through `conda install`.